# shell script running infinitely

Tags: shell, unix

i have a shell script `run.sh`.

```
cd elasticsearch-1.1.0/
./bin/elasticsearch
cd
cd RBlogs/DataFetcher/
mvn clean install assembly:single;
cd target/
java -jar DataFetcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Here if second line(`./bin/elasticsearch`) executes it runs infinite time, so the next lines will not execute. So what i need is to perform the next lines after 10 seconds. But

```
cd elasticsearch-1.1.0/
./bin/elasticsearch
sleep 10
cd
cd RBlogs/DataFetcher/
mvn clean install assembly:single;
cd target/
java -jar DataFetcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

This also will not execute next lines because `./bin/elasticsearch` will not complete its execution in 10seconds. So how can i solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: You can run your command in the background by appending an ampersand `./bin/elasticsearch &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `&` at the end of `./bin/elasticsearch` will cause the process to run in a subshell, freeing the current shell up for the next commands.

```
./bin/elasticsearch &
```

Change this in your second version of the script and things should run like you want them too.

More information can be found from `man bash`

```
If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell 
executes the command in the background in a subshell. 
The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try to put it in background

```
&
```

can do this for you

```
./bin/elasticsearch &
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want `elasticsearch` to run in the background while the rest of the script progresses, just use `&`:

```
cd elasticsearch-1.1.0/
./bin/elasticsearch &
sleep 10
cd
cd RBlogs/DataFetcher/
```

However, if you want to run `elasticsearch` for at most 10 seconds, killing it if necessary, then proceeding with the rest of the script, you need something a little more complicated:

```
cd elasticsearch-1.1.0/
./bin/elasticsearch &
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -0 $pid && kill $pid
cd
cd RBlogs/DataFetcher/
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mentioned, you can

1. use `./bin/elasticsearch &` to run the command in
   background.
2. record the process id of the
       command run in background by using `child_pid=$!` and then stop the
       process by using `kill $child_pid` after some time to implement a
       timeout mechanism.

Meanwhile, you also can synchronize another operation with the command run in background by using `wait` command. An example bellow:

```
./bin/elasticsearch &
# do something asynchronously here
wait # wait for accomplishment of ./bin/elasticsearch
# do something synchronously here
```